# Android app record clicks

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app which is not connected to any server but requires internet connection. The app has a map with some markers on it. I want to record how many times each marker has been clicked by all users of the app. So something like if someone clicks on this marker, record that the marker with name_of_marker has been clicked +1. Then i want to view those statistics (basically i want to know which marker is being clicked the most by the users of the app). In which ways can i do this ? Do i need to have a server and ping calls to it or something ? Any free tools for doing this ? I'm really new to this sort of stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for doing this would be to integrate an **`analytics sdk`** like [firebase analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) which would help you record any **`custom events`**(clicks, page load events etc). Integrating one such analytics sdk has got a lot of other advantages like tracking graphical representations, user patterns etc. In your case, this can also help you to track *which marker is being clicked the most by the users of the app*

See more info about firebase analytics **[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)**